# Add new fields using c # code to crystal report (rpt)

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, windows-forms-designer

I have a crystal report rpt report created with some fixed fields that fill with a datatable, the fields obtained in the datatable may vary depending on the SQL statement of the fields in a form. Therefore, the question is whether in the design of the rpt form I can add, by code, new fields obtained in the datatable. For example, in the datatable I get the First and Last Name fields, and I show them in the report (in the design I have inserted the First and Last Name fields). Now in the datatable I get Name, Surname and Telephone, if I call the same report, it will fill in only Name and Surname, the Telephone field, not being inserted in the report will not appear, the idea is to add it. I am filling the dataset in such a way:

```
DataSet ds = new dsDataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
    foreach (DataColumn column in dtBusqueda.Columns)
    {
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
    }
```

Now it would be those dataset fields to insert into the report as I explained before. The report is loaded as follows:

```
ReportDocument Report = new ReportDocument();
Report.Load("../../crReporte.rpt");
Report.SetDataSource(dtDataTable);
frmReportes form = new frmReportes(Report);
form.Show();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal work only with pre-defined data object to display the data in a specified format. So if you pass a different data object then it will give you errors that it cannot locate your column.

I can offer :

1) Use same dataTable source for all (put tel column in original). So set visibility on Crystal Report for your special column. with supress.

2) You can create individual 2 different report And in your If Case you can load another report template if you want.

if it is only tel number not for complex requirement. use way 1. just set visibility.
But if you have complex requirement. I think you should use 2 different report template.